# Как найти внутри тега неопределенное значение используя JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div class='user'><img src='*' class='avatar float-left'>
<div>нужное значение*</div></div>
```

Есть страница HTML. В данном коде нужно вывести только "нужное значение*" используя JS. На странице таких div целая куча, так что по номеру не пойдет. "Нужное значение*" через определенное время заменяется на случайное слово (ник юзера).
Может есть вариант как-то найти по классу 'user' и внутри с div вывести это "нужное значение*"? 
Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
function find_name()
{var value_name = document.getElementsByClassName("userinfo");
document.title = value_name.innerHTML;
}
```

Естественно, данного кода не достаточно и в title летит "undefined".
Может есть какой-то вариант через JS докинуть в нужное значение* хотя бы id на лету? Т.е. чтоб получилось нужное значение*. Напомню, при загрузке страницы "нужное значение*" уже подставлено и следующее не известно - не повторяется. Страница чужая и заменить нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Плохо понял Вас

```js
const value = document.querySelector('.user.name .avatar + div')

console.log(value.textContent)
```

```html
<div class='user name'>
  <img src='*' class='avatar float-left'>
  <div>нужное значение*</div>
</div>

<div class='user'>
  <img src='*' class='avatar float-left'>
  <div>не нужное значение*</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если кратко и чуть по другому, то мне нужно то, что между тегом <div>, а это "нужное значение*". Это значение какое пойдет на вывод не известно. Полученный результат нужно присвоить переменной, дабы потом использовать в нужных целях. Например, в title страницы вывести полученный результат. Всё это дабро вешается на страницу через Tampermonkey с добавлением JS.
Кажется, ваш способ подошел. Буду пробовать в боевых условиях.

Comment: Между каким тегом div?

Comment: <div>нужное значение*</div>
Проблема заключалась в том, что я не мог обратиться к данному div через getElementBy, т.к. тег не содержит class или id. а на странице div очень много.

Comment: то я показал через какой селектор обратиться, мой код выводит что внутри div(нужное значение*)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как обращаться к <div class='user name'> если содержится пробел? Аналогично коду как и ранее, добавив лишь пробел и name.

Comment: В смылсе что `<div class='user'>` теперь `<div class='user name'>`? Код и так будет работать